# Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular, typescript

### Details

I am trying to implement ng2-select in form there are two issue first it shows this error because i using table in which users are shown when click on username it redirect to another component and show that specific users data like email, roles and group when I will go back and select other data it shows this error.

> Expression has changed after it was checked.
>   [image]

another issue is this I am using 2 ng2-select in same form and both of this show same initData

### code Typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { InviteUserComponent } from './invite-user.component';
import { UserListComponent } from './user-list.component';
import { SimpleNotificationsComponent } from 'angular2-notifications';
import { AuthorizeUserDirective } from '../../directives/authorize-user.directive';
import { UserService} from '../../services/user.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth/auth.service';
import {SELECT_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-select';

@Component({
    selector: 'users-edit',
    templateUrl: '../../app/components/user/user-edit.html',
    directives: [SELECT_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class UserEditComponent implements OnInit{
    private isAdmin: Boolean = false;
    private _data: Observable<any[]>;
    private fname: string;
    private id: number;
    private lname: string;
    private email: string;
    private _roles: Observable<any[]>;
    public roles: any = [];
    public groups: any = [];
    private initRoleData: Array<any>[] = []; 
    private initGroupData: Array<any>[] = [];


    public selected(value: any): void {
        console.log('Selected value is: ', value);
    }

    public removed(value: any): void {
        console.log('Removed value is: ', value);
    }

    public refreshValue(value: any): void {
        this.initRoleData = value;
    }


    constructor(private router: Router,
        private userService: UserService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private authService: AuthService) {

        this.isCurrentUserAdmin();
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.id = +params['id'];
        });
    }

    private isCurrentUserAdmin() {
        this.userService.isCurrentUserAdmin(this.authService.getUserName())
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.isAdmin = Boolean(data);
            },
            error => {
                console.log("error while retriving admin");
                console.log(error);
                this.userService.handleError(error);
            });
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.userService.getUser(this.id)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.fname = data.FirstName;
                this.lname = data.LastName;
                this.email = data.Email;
            });

        this.userService.getUserRolesById(this.id)
            .subscribe(data => {
                data.forEach(role => {
                    this.initRoleData.push(role.Name);
                });
            });

        this.userService.getUserGroupsById(this.id)
            .subscribe(data => {
                data.forEach(group => {
                    this.initGroupData.push(group.Name);
                });
            });

        this.userService.getAllRoles()
            .subscribe(data => {
                data.forEach(role => {
                    this.roles.push(role.Name);
                });
            });

        this.userService.getAllGroups()
            .subscribe(data => {
                data.forEach(group => {
                    this.groups.push(group.Name);
                });
            });

    }



    Submit(form: any)
    {
        alert(form);

    }

}
```

### html

```html
<div class="row margin-bottom-40" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- Reg-Form -->
        <form id="sky-form4" class="sky-form" (ngSubmit)="Submit(userEdit)" #userEdit="ngForm">
            <header>Edit User Account</header>

            <fieldset>
                <section>
                    <label class="input">
                        <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="First Name" required [value]="fname">
                        <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Enter First Name</b>
                    </label>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <label class="input">
                        <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Last Name" [value]="lname">
                        <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Enter Last Name</b>
                    </label>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <label class="input">
                        <i class="icon-append fa fa-envelope"></i>
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" [value]="email">
                        <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Enter Email Address</b>
                    </label>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <label>
                        Roles
                    </label>
                    <div *ngIf="roles.length > 0">
                        <ng-select [initData]="initRoleData"
                                   [multiple]="true"
                                   [items]="roles"
                                   (data)="refreshValue($event)"
                                   (selected)="selected($event)"
                                   (removed)="removed($event)"
                                   placeholder="No roles assign">
                        </ng-select>
                    </div>
                </section>
                
                <section>
                    <label>
                        Groups
                    </label>
                    <div *ngIf="groups.length > 0">
                        <ng-select [initData]="initGroupData"
                                   [multiple]="true"
                                   [items]="groups"
                                   (data)="refreshValue($event)"
                                   (selected)="selected($event)"
                                   (removed)="removed($event)"
                                   placeholder="No groups assign">
                        </ng-select>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </fieldset>
            <footer>
                <button type="reset" class="btn-u">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn-u" [disabled]="!userEdit.form.valid">Save</button>
            </footer>
        </form>
        <!-- End Reg-Form -->
    </div>

</div><!--/end row-->
```

Comment: Is `initialApprover` a term of your source or is this from Angular2?

Comment: it is a response get from api and which I shown in ng2-select

Comment: Can you try to create a Plunker that allows to reproduce (Plunker has a built in Angular2 TS template using the "new" button) and try to reduce the source as much as possible. What are these APIs. Are these all `http.get()` calls or do you use other libraries to call to the server?

Comment: as for APIs It is locally developed and for now it is only `http.get()` call to get user roles and groups from api and show it in ng2-select

Comment: It doesn't look like it's caused by the code you posted. Usually this error message is caused by some event that is not patched by Angulars zone. Angular2 runs change detection after an event happened. In your case it seems an event happened and the event handler modified the model and with the next change detection Angular2 is wondering how that could happen that a value is different than before without Angular2 noticing. You can invoke change detection manually to satisfy Angular2 in this event handler, ore use `zone.run(...)` to make the code run inside Angulars zone so it gets notified.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer could you please give me some zone change detection example in my case because I have no clue about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved by adding ChangeDetectionStrategy from angular core.
And also added in the Component.

```
import {  Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'page1',
  templateUrl: 'page1.html',
})
```